# Ryzen APU with "Radeon Graphics" - How to get graphics specification data for each APU model?

Tags: laptop, gpu, integrated-graphics, amd-ryzen, specifications

With a view to purchasing a notebook with a Ryzen APU (according to AMD´s term for their CPUs with integrated GPU), I was about looking for graphics specifications for the different Ryzen models. Hours of online search on AMD processors "with Radeon Graphics" revealed nothing to me other than graphics frequency and deployable graphics cores, ploughing through AMD´s website was of no avail either.

How can I get more detailed, reliable information on the "Ryzen Mobile Processors with Radeon Graphics", such as DirectX or OpenCL? It is a mystery to me how one should decide upon purchasing a certain GPU without information on the most common basic data in advance. There has to be some kind of official outline or announcement about what graphics specifications go with each APU or with "Radeon Graphics", does it?

I would rather expect a number of questions on this matter but couldn´t find even one. I wonder what I am missing. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would check APU compare sites and see how they stack up against each other, and shop based on that. Things like support for DirectX and OpenCL are usually mentioned on them if it matters, or absent if it is not an issue (eg. always supported)

Comment: The best you can usually do is Google the APU number and "benchmark video" where you will most likely find some real indication of playable power.

Comment: @LPChip & Mokubai: That´s really helpful to me as now I know there´s no hope in spending even more time with searching for further clues. I´m sorry to say however that the "benchmark video" solution is beyond me entirely as I am not familiar with this world at all and I can´t afford digging into this deep enough to put to use in this lifetime. Many thanks for sharing your much appreciated experience!

Comment: a benchmark video or benchmark result will generate a score. You can compare this score against multiple devices, and when you watch a video, the benchmark is part of a review, and that review will tell you more about what devices are useful. If you say you don't have time, then that means we can't help you. We don't do recommendations because they get outdated really fast.

Comment: @LPChip : Please take my apologies for not being clear, as I now realise. I wanted to say that you have helped me ALREADY and I´m happy with your answers, I didn´t intend a further request by any means. Of course I also want to thank you for this recent, further information and explanation, and I am absolutely fine with everything you say. Don´t get me wrong though: I am good with spending time all right, my background however I deem not sufficient to go for what is required here because, considering my background, I perceive the time I CAN spend will never suffice.